# How to add values to a list while iterating it

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I Have a scenario such like this

```
List<String> xxx = new ArrayList
for(String yyy : xxx){
   for(String zzz:xyxy){
     if(!zzz.equals(yyy)){
       xxx.add(zzz);
     }
   }
}
```

But i get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null exception.Can anyone help me solve this issue.? Can anyone give me alternate method to perform this ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As an aside, you need to work on your variable naming skills. Your sample code is hard to follow solely due to the non-descriptive names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [`ArrayList` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So you're going to need to explicitly get a `ListIterator` and use that to properly alter your `ArrayList`. Also, I don't believe you can use a for-each loop because the iterators in those are separate from your explicitly retrieved iterator. I think you'll have to use a while loop:

```
List<String> xxx = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator<String> iterator = xxx.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    for (String zzz : xyxy) {
        if (!zzz.equals(s)) {
            iterator.add(zzz); //<-- Adding is done through the iterator
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo thanks bro .. It worked like a gem ...!

Comment: What is xyxy in above for each loop?

Comment: @Rajper I presume it's an `Iterable<String>` of some kind. What specific kind it is, I don't know. It was in the original question, so I just left it that way.

Comment: Yeah definitely it is some kind of String collection, but what I was trying to ask; It must be declared or initialized somewhere in  the snippet.

Comment: @Rajper I assume the missing declaration was just forgotten or something. It isn't a significant detail for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add them in another list and then add that list to `xxx`;

```
List<String> xxx = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> additional = new ArrayList<>();
for (String yyy : xxx) {
    for (String zzz : xyxy) {
        if (!zzz.equals(yyy)) {
            additional.add(zzz);
        }
    }
}
xxx.addAll(additional);
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify a list while iterating you can declare the arraylist as "**java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList**"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> xxx = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
    xxx.add("3");
    xxx.add("4");

    List<String> xyxy = new ArrayList();
    xyxy.add("1");
    xyxy.add("2");
    xyxy.add("3");

    for (String yyy : xxx) {
        for (String zzz : xyxy) {
            if (!zzz.equals(yyy)) {
                xxx.add(zzz);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(xxx);
}
```

Comment: However, according to the online API, "The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created". This could be problematic, depending on what OP wants. Also, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`s are horrible for performance if you don't have a ton more reads than writes

Comment: Agreed. CopyOnWriteArrayList will be effective when number of modifications are minimal compared to number of traversal operations.

Comment: Which doesn't seem to be the case here...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a foreach loop, but use a normal loop like:

```
int originalSize=xxx.size();
for (int i=0;i<originalSize;i++) {
    xxx.add("New string appended at the end");
}
```

This allows you to iterate **only** on the items present in the list **before** you start to iterate, and it works if your only operation on the list is to add some new item at the end of it.

Comment: Don't do this! `xxx.size()` is chaging while `originalSize` stays the same.

Comment: @ginz this is done on purpose! To iterate only on the items that are originally contained in the list (and not in the new items added during the loop)

Comment: It's not the same behavior as in author's code.

Comment: The intent of the OP is not really specified. But if you set the condition for ending the loop by checking xxx.size() you have the risk to have an infinite loop (if you continue to add new item).

Answer (score 0):

It means you cannot access and modify your collection (List) at the same time. To do so you must use an iterator. I dont understand what xyxy is in your code. but a possible iteration and adittion of element might look like this.

```
        List<String> xxx = new ArrayList<String>();

        xxx.add("hello");
        xxx.add("hi");
        xxx.add("hh");

        ListIterator<String> it = xxx.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            if (!it.next().equals("hi")) {
                it.remove();
                it.add("hi");

            }
        }

        System.out.println(xxx);
          }
      }
```

Comment: I believe this would still throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're still modifying the `ArrayList` in a way that isn't through the iterator itself